What is the name of the highlight group used by the Neovim lsp inlay_hint?
I'm using Neovim v0.10.0 with lspconfig. The lsp inlay_hint is enabled in the on_attach function like this:
local on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
  if client.server_capabilities.inlayHintProvider then
    vim.lsp.inlay_hint.enable(true, { bufnr = bufnr })
  end
end

In this case, I'm testing with Go. The rangeVariableTypes hint is enabled for golsp and I can see the hints appear for ranges. In my color scheme, the hints have the same color as normal text, but I want to change the hints to be italic and grey. However, so far I have not been able to figure out what the highlight group neovim uses for the hints. :InspectTree does not display tokens for the hints.
